# How to parse and use both HTML and variable with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending a JS file a bunch of HTML. The JS file simply uses JQuery to render the HTML to the page, eg:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax/nocache/someurl',
  type: 'html',
  success: function(html) {
    $('.wrapper').html(html);
  }
});
```

This works fine.

However, I now need to send an array of data, eg:

```
  [
    'hash' => $hash,
    'html' => $rendered_html,
  ]
```

I am unsure how to modify my JS above to accept and use both the HTML and hash.

Would anyone know how I could go about this?

Comment: Just parse the JSON response into variables and use them? Or am I misunderstanding something

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using `dataType.'json'` eg:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/ajax/nocache/someurl',
  dataType.'json',
  success: function(html) {
    var hash = result.hash;
    $('.wrapper').html(result.html);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var request = $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/nocache/someurl',
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        id: menuId
    },
    dataType: 'json',
});

request.done(function(response) {
    var hash = result.hash;
    $('.wrapper').html(response.data);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try to put them inside each other something like that

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'json',
  url: '/ajax/nocache/someurl',
  data: 'hash',
  success: function(json) {
  // do what ever you wanna do with json
    $.ajax({
    type: 'html',
    url: '/ajax/nocache/someurl',
    data: 'hash',
    success: function(json) {
      $('.wrapper').html(html);
    }
   });
});
```